# Simplifying an expression of the second partial derivative w.r.t x

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I've been simplifying an expression for a few hours, but I have a little trouble in understanding the last few steps to get to the desired expression. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

\begin{align*}
f_{xx}(t,x) &= \frac{\left(-6 t^{3/2} x e^{\frac{x^2}{4 t}}-6 t^{5/2} x e^{\frac{3 x^2}{4 t}}+t^{3/2} x^3 e^{\frac{3 x^2}{4 t}}-12 t^2 x e^{\frac{x^2}{2 t}}-\sqrt{t} x^3 e^{\frac{x^2}{4 t}}\right)}{4 t^5\left(e^{\frac{x^2}{4 t}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^4} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{t} x e^{\frac{x^2}{2 t}} \left(x^2-6 t\right)-x e^{\frac{x^2}{4 t}} \left(6 t+x^2\right)}{4 t^{5/2} \left(\sqrt{t} e^{\frac{x^2}{4 t}}+1\right)^3}
\end{align*}

The original expression is as follows,
\begin{equation*}
f(t,x) = \frac{\left(1/t\right)^{3/2} x\exp\left(-x^2/4t\right)}{t^{-1/2}\exp\left(-x^2/4t\right)+1}
\end{equation*}

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what is the original expression?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: no i meant $f(t,x)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Ah, edited my post again.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator of $f(t, x)$ by $\exp(x^2/4t)$ to simplify things first.

Comment: @AlexG Hi, I'm trying to simplify $f_{xx}(t,x)$, and already simplified $f(t,x) $.

Comment: I'm saying, if you make the change I suggested, what you compute for $f_{xx}$ will probably be simpler.

Comment: @AlexG. Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but I was trying to say I already did what you suggested, and arrived to the second partial derivative at the top, and am now trying to simplify that expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-6t^{5/2}xe^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}+t^{3/2}x^3e^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}-12t^2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^3}{4t}}}{4t^5\left(e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt t}\right)^4}$$
$$=\frac{-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-6t^{5/2}xe^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}+t^{3/2}x^3e^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}-12t^2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^3}{4t}}}{4t^5\left(\frac{\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1}{\sqrt t}\right)^4}$$
$$=\frac{-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-6t^{5/2}xe^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}+t^{3/2}x^3e^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}-12t^2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^3}{4t}}}{4t^5\frac{\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^4}{t^2}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{t}\left(-6txe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-6t^{2}xe^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}+tx^3e^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}-12t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-x^3e^{\frac{x^3}{4t}}\right)}{4t^3\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^4}$$
$$=\frac{-6txe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-6t^{2}xe^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}+tx^3e^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}-12t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-x^3e^{\frac{x^3}{4t}}}{4t^{5/2}\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^4}$$
$$=\small\frac{tx^3e^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}-6t^2xe^{\frac{3x^2}{4t}}-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}+\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6txe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{4t^{5/2}\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^4}$$

$$=\small\frac{\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}\left(\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6txe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right)+\left(\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6txe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right)}{4t^{5/2}\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^4}$$

$$=\frac{\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)\left(\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6txe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right)}{4t^{5/2}\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^4}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt tx^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6t^{3/2}xe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}-6txe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}-x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{4t^{5/2}\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^3}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt txe^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}(x^2-6t)-xe^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}(6t+x^2)}{4t^{5/2}\left(\sqrt te^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}+1\right)^3}$$

Comment: It was really elegant how you factored out the $t^2$ and then multiplied top and bottom by $t^{-1/2}$, thanks again.

Comment: @Jun-GooKwak: Glad to help you. You are welcome.